# Installing Sage on Spyder?

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, sage

Can I use pip install to install SageMath on Spyder (on Anaconda)? If so, how? I have tried the following already:

```bash
$ curl -L -O https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge/releases/latest/download/ ˓→Mambaforge-$(uname)-$(uname -m).sh
$ sh Mambaforge-$(uname)-$(uname -m).sh
```

particularly on Spyder itself, but I cannot seem to make anything happen. I am very much a beginner with Python, and I am trying to install SageMath, but have no idea how to go about it.

Is there a command I can use to install SageMath on Spyder on Anaconda? I've tried

```bash
$ sage --pip install
```

among others, but it seems like I am truly missing something and I am not able to figure something out.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I've clarified the question a bit.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Please open a terminal or the Anaconda Prompt and run there: `conda create -n sage-env -c conda-forge sage`. Then follow the instructions in [our docs](http://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/faq.html#using-existing-environment) to understand how to connect that environment to Spyder.

Answer (score 2):

Under GNU/Linux or macOS,
Sage can be installed for Conda.

See: [SageMath installation guide: Install from conda-forge](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/installation/conda.html).

Use the "conda-forge" Conda channel,
see comment by @Carlos_Cordoba.

Under Windows, one needs to use the
"Windows Subsystem for Linux" (WSL).